# Select checkbox to visible dropdowns in table using Angular

Tags: angular

In table label followed by dropdown is available, I'm trying to implement If we select checkbox only dropdown should be visible and label should be hidden. By default label should be visible. I tried below code, please suggest me the solution.

```
 this.http.get(dataUrl).subscribe(response => {
      this.persons = response.data.map(x=>({...x,check:false,test:x.firstName}));
      this.dtTrigger.next();
    });
```

html code:

```
<select [disabled]="!person.check?true:null" [(ngModel)]="person.dropdown" (change)="selected(person.dropdown)">  
      <option *ngFor="let prod of ProductHeader" [value]="prod.name" >{{prod.name}}</option>
    </select>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/drop-down-population-t5ngwp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `*ngIf` maybe. Like this:

```
<span *ngIf="person.check"></span>
<select *ngIf="person.check">
```

If not, please update you question, because it is pretty unclear what you are after.

See, for example, you title: 'show dropdown only checkbox selected' is not a good English sentence.